# jquery data() not attaching values

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to attach some data to `options` in a `select` menu of a particular class using jquery `data()` that are coming from a jquery `ajax()` call. But I am getting the error that it is not getting attached when I try to call it. Or, more accurately that it is not getting applied at all, as the `console.log($(this).data('address'.vendorName));` in the antipenultimate line of code below gives me the error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'vendorName' of undefined`

The inner `$.each()` loop is a last-stab attempt because I thought that perhaps just using 
`$('.vendor_address_id_' + id).data....` wasn't being applied to all the elements with that class. But I don't really think it should be necessary. What am I doing wrong?

```
$.each(returnedData, function (key, val) {
    var id = val.id;

    //attach address information to each select option for display in .vendor_full_address_table
    $('.vendor_address_id_' + id).each(function (k, v) {

        $(this).data('address', {
            'vendorName': val.vendor_name,
            'address1': val.address1,
            'address2': val.address2,
            'city': val.city,
            'state': val.state,
            'zip': val.zip
        });
        //gives error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'vendorName' of undefined 
        console.log($(this).data('address').vendorName);
    });
});



//console.log(returnedData);
Object
    address_0: Object
        address1: "street address1"
        address2: ""
        city: "Kalamazoo"
        id: "15"
        state: "MI"
        vendor_name: "companyA"
        zip: "123456"
    address_1: Object
        etc...
        etc...
        etc...
    address_2: Object
        etc...
        etc...
        etc...
```

Comment: Make it easy on us: post this on jsFiddle and remove the code that you think shouldn't be necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
val.vendor_name
```

Use

```
returnedData.vendor_name
```

Here **val** is the Value of the particular `returnedData[key]` value in the iteration.

And you are trying to access a property from a primitive type which is the **val** here .

Comment: well, the key is `vendorName`. I set it with `$(this).data('address', {'vendorName': val.vendor_name,` Have you edited your answer from what it was originally? I thought when I first loaded this page, it said that I should change `val` to `returnedData`. Thank you very much for you help.